# Убрать функция ().call(this) в CoffeeScript на Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

Весь JS-код, сгенерированный из исходников на CoffeeScript оборачивается в анонимную функцию с немедленным вызовом (IIFE), вроде:

```
(function(){
  // мой код
}).call(this)
```

Как можно убрать эту обёртку, чтобы остался **только мой код**? Дело происходит в Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/5693211/2076787

Answer (score 1):

*Это крайние меры. Идите на это только в том случае, если на все 100% уверены, что это лучший выход из вашей ситуации. А подобные ситуации весьма редки.*

---

В самом CoffeeScript за это отвечает опция `b`/`bare`. Осталось понять, как её включить.

Если закопаться в исходники, выясняется, что преобразованием CoffeeScript в Ruby on Rails занимается [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt). И из [исходного кода](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/v2.0.7/lib/tilt/coffee.rb#L18) легко понять, где там включается `bare`:

```
Tilt::CoffeeScriptTemplate.default_bare = true
```

Где проставить — это уже на ваш выбор.

Если у вас по всему проекту так должно быть, можно создать файл-инициализатор, скажем, `config/initializers/tilt.rb`. Где разместить эту строчку, предварительно  сделав `require "tilt/coffee"` (см. путь к файлу внутри Tilt, начиная с папки `lib`), т. к. это самое начало загрузки, и необходимые определения могли на этот момент ещё не выполниться.